# How to use textScrollList to select a material?

Tags: python, arguments, user-defined-functions, maya

I'm trying to make a materials manager using textScrollList. This is my first code and I'm using this tool to teach myself Python for Maya. Currently, my code lists the materials in the scene, but they are not selectable.

The problem I am running into is making the listed materials selectable. I think I am incorrectly defining 'dcc'.

Any help at all in what I'm misunderstanding or doing incorrectly would be awesome! Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def getSelectedMaterial(*arg):
    selection = cmds.textScrollList(materialsList, query=True, si=True)
    print selection

cmds.window(title='My Materials List', width=200)

cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

materialsList = cmds.ls(mat=True)

cmds.textScrollList('materials', append=materialsList, dcc="getSelectedMaterial()") 
cmds.showWindow()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening here:

```
selection = cmds.textScrollList(materialsList, query=True, si=True)
```

You defined `materialsList` to be all the materials but the `cmds.textScrollList()` is expecting the instance of the `textScrollList` that you are trying to query, which you called 'materials'.

Replace that line with this one:

```
selection = cmds.textScrollList('materials', query=True, si=True)
```

Generally with GUI elements I like to make a variable that captures the result of the element creation then you can use the variable later to query or edit.

Like this:

```
myTextList = cmds.textScrollList('materials', append=materialsList, dcc="getSelectedMaterial()") 
print cmds.textScrollList(myTextList, query=True, si=True)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors!

I follow what you're saying, but making those changes is only causing the code to print the name of the material. It still is not selecting it. Any ideas?

Comment: that is because the method you made named getSelectedMaterial() is just printing the name. if you want it to select the material change the line from 'print selection' to cmds.select(selection, replace=True)

Answer (score 0):

Explanations in the comments of the script !

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def getSelectedMaterial(*args):
    selection = cmds.textScrollList("material", query=True, si=True)
    cmds.select( selection )

cmds.window(title='My Materials List', width=200)

cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

materialsList = cmds.ls(mat=True)
# remove quote for the command flag
# you can give a name to your control but if there is duplicates, it wont work
cmds.textScrollList("material", append=materialsList, dcc=getSelectedMaterial) 

cmds.showWindow()

#  A Better Way to do it :====================================================================================

from functools import partial

def doWhateverMaterial(mat=str):
    # my function are written outside ui scope so i can use them without the ui
    cmds.select(mat)

def ui_getSelectedMaterial(scroll, *args):
    # def ui_function() is used to query ui variable and execute commands
    # for a simple select, i wouldn't separate them into two different command
    # but you get the idea.
    selection = cmds.textScrollList(scroll, query=True, si=True)
    doWhateverMaterial(selection )

cmds.window(title='My Materials List', width=200)

cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

materialsList = cmds.ls(mat=True)

# we init the scroll widget because we want to give it to the function
# even if you set the name : 'material', there is a slight possibility that this
# name already exists, so we capture the name in variable 'mat_scroll'
mat_scroll = cmds.textScrollList(append=materialsList)
# here we give to our parser the name of the control we want to query
# we use partial to give arguments from a ui command to another function
# template : partial(function, arg1, arg2, ....)
cmds.textScrollList(mat_scroll, e=True, dcc=partial(ui_getSelectedMaterial, mat_scroll))

cmds.showWindow()
```